# Remove the number at the end of string depending which number appears the end

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I have a data frame which I would like to iterate over the rows and remove the number at the end depending of which number appears at the end. If the number is between [0 to 5] I would like to remove 1 number and if the number is equal to 20, I would like to remove 2 number at the end of each word.

I designed the general code, however I dont know how to define if a word in a row ends to 0 to 5 or only it ends to 20, can you help me to solve this problem?

```
def vvv (df):
    for index, row in df.iterrows:

        

>     if   row['FT'] ends to a number from 1 to 5

        row['FT'] = row['FT'].str.replace(r'\d$', '', regex=True)

>     if   row['FT'] ends to  20


        row['FT'] = row['FT'].str.replace(r'\d\d$', '', regex=True)
    
    return df
```

Update: I designed the code as follows but I get another error of TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable

```
def vvv(df):
    for index, row in df.iterrows:
        row['FT'] = row['FT'].str.replace(r'\([1-9]|10)$', '', regex=True)
        row['FT'] = row['FT'].str.replace(r'_$', '', regex=True)
    return df
```

Comment: Use [`([1-5]|20)$`](https://regex101.com/r/LWQbgT/1)

Comment: `row['FT'] = row['FT'].str.replace(r'(?<!\d)(?:[0-5]|20)$', '', regex=True)`?

Comment: Thanks Olivin, I did your way and updated the question with the code but I get the error of TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable
any idea?

Comment: @ella, you missed parentheses `df.iterrows()`

Comment: TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable
I get this error Wiktor

Comment: yes true but now it is another error of AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
?

Comment: @ella, isn't error message explicit enough? Look at code you've written, what it does, where result stored

Comment: Sorry, it should be `df['FT']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
df['FT'] = df['FT'].str.replace(r'(?<!\d)(?:[0-5]|20)$', '', regex=True)
```

**Regex details**:

- `(?<!\d)` - a left-hand digit boundary (no digit immediately on the left is allowed)
- `(?:[0-5]|20)` - `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5` or `20`
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jnPHqi/1).

If you plan to also remove whitespaces before the numbers, you can add `.str.strip()` or `.str.rstrip()`. Or, use a `\s*(?<!\d)(?:[0-5]|20)$` regex (see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jnPHqi/2)), but I'd use `strip`.

Comment: is this correct if I want to remove only 20 ? 

df['FT'] = df['FT'].str.replace(r'(?:20)$', '', regex=True)

Comment: @ella `r'(?<!\d)20$'` or `r'\s+20$'` will do.